# Error Building apk Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, java-9

I am having real trouble with building an Android apk for my Unity project. Now, when I try to build it, this error shows:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to build apk.
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-9.0.1\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:/Users/josem/AppData/Local/Android/sdk\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" -

stderr[
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at SDKMain.main(SDKMain.java:130)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/misc/BASE64Encoder
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.build.SignedJarBuilder.<init>(SignedJarBuilder.java:177)
    at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.init(ApkBuilder.java:446)
    at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.<init>(ApkBuilder.java:422)
    at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.<init>(ApkBuilder.java:362)
    at UnityApkBuilder.<init>(UnityApkBuilder.java:214)
    at UnityApkBuilder.main(UnityApkBuilder.java:34)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.misc.BASE64Encoder
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:466)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:563)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    ... 11 more
]
stdout[

]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandInternal (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandSafe (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

I have tried several times to change sdk tools version because many similar questions are solved finding a compatible one but not my case. Right now I'm using 24.4.1. I have also tried deleting Unity/Project/Temp folder and moving zipalign.exe from build-tools to tools due to other build errors that I had.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason being is that you are using **Java 9 (JDK 9)**. Based on the information from [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/java-9-jdk-9-support-by-unity-android.499354/) Unity forum thread, you need to use **Java 8 (JDK 8)** instead.

Comment: Depending on JDK intern classes such as sun.misc.BASE64Encoder has always been fragile. Has anyone submitted a bug to Android apk to make them aware of this issue? Java SE 8 added java.util.Base64 as a standard API for base64 encoding and decoding.

Comment: @AlanBateman I've flagged this as a duplicate. And the answer there has a  Bug link to trace it as well.